# Swift: NSNumber is not a subtype of Float

Tags: swift

I tried the code from Swift Programming Language in playground and got the following error "NSNumber is not a subtype of Float", I just modified it slightly by making x and y of type Float in struct Point.  What am I missing?

[image: Code]

If I added Float type to centerX and centerY, I got error: Could not find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which line has the mistake? Keep in mind the only difference between my code and the Apple's sample code is I typed Point x and y as Float but Apple initialize it to 0.0.

Comment: try `size.width / 2.0f`

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Same error as the first.

Comment: Please paste code instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is completely unrelated to the actual error... The actual error is cannot convert `Double` to `Float`.

In `Size`, `x` and `y` are `Double` (default type of float literal) but in `Point`, `width` and `height` are `Float`. They are different types and you can't mix them without explicit conversion.

There are number of ways to fix it. You can change them all to `Double` or `Float`.

e.g.

```
class Point
{
   var x:Double
   var y:Double
}
```

or you can convert them to correct type by doing `Float(centerX)`

ps: can you post the code next time so I can change it without retype them

Comment: If this is really the answer, that's a pretty terrible error message.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Yes... Compiler somehow decide to convert `Double` to `NSNumber` (because it can) and found it can't convert `NSNumber` to `Float`. For second one it is better. Just means no `operator / (Double, Double) -> Float` exist (or something similar)

Comment: Points are a pain when in iphone 32 bit. I wish they had a solution.